# Не отображать свойство во View согласно условию

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В контролере я беру информацию о школе и посредством ViewModel отображаю ее во View:

**HomeController.cs**

```
IRepository<monit95App.Domain.Core.school> schoolRepository;

public ActionResult GetInfo()
{
    school current_school = schoolRepository.GetT(User.Identity.Name);
    var vm = new InfoVM();

    vm.LoginMonit95 = current_school.SchoolID;
    vm.AreaName = current_school.area.AreaName;
    vm.TownTypeName = current_school.towntype.TownTypeName;

    vm.Email = current_school.SchoolEmail ?? "Не указан";

    return View(vm);
}
```

**InfoVM.cs**

```
  public class InfoVM
    {
        [Display(Name = "Логин на сайте www.monit95.ru:")]
        public string LoginMonit95 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Район:")]
        public string AreaName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Тип населенного пункта:")]
        public string TownTypeName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email:")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Код ГИА:")]
        public int? LoginGIA { get; set; } //ЭТО ПОЛЕ У НЕКОТОРЫХ ШКОЛ В БАЗЕ РАВНО NULL        
    }
```

**GetInfo.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LoginMonit95, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="form-control-static">
        @Model.LoginMonit95
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AreaName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="form-control-static">
        @Model.AreaName
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.TownTypeName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="form-control-static">
        @Model.TownTypeName
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="form-control-static">
        @Model.Email
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Задача:** Необходимо отобразить поле `LoginGIA` для школ у которых оно не равно `NULL`. Во ViewModel я это поле уже прописал. Вот как теперь правильно прописать код в `контролере` и `View` для решения этой задачи?

Comment: никак: `int` - это тип-значение, он не может быть `null`

Comment: только если так public int? LoginGIA { get; set; }

Comment: @Grundy так в БД у некоторых школ оно равно `null`. Или мне как-то `ViewModel` необходимо перестроить? Я не понял что ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: @adamshakhabov имеется в виду, что переменная типа `int` сама по себе не может иметь значение равное `null`. А чтобы это было возможно, необходимо изменить тип поля на `int?`.
А вообще мне вот не совсем ясно зачем дублировать поля модели во вью-модели. добавьте модель во мью-модель целиком то. `vm.school = current_school`, зачем по каждому полю перетаскивать данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставьте этот код внутрь внешнего div'a:

```
@if (Model.LoginGIA != null)
{
    Html.LabelFor(x => x.LoginMonit95, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="form-control-static">
        @Model.LoginMonit95
    </div>
}
```

Comment: да не будет Model.LoginGIA null никогда, будет 0 в противном случае

Comment: @tCode что ему мешает быть `null` если он `int?` ?

Comment: @teran уже писали выше, что тип int не может принимать значение NULL, а может принимать целочисленные значения в диапазоне от -2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647 и значением по умолчанию для типа int является 0, исключением является тип Nullable Int (int?), который может принимать значение null

Comment: забавно, автор отредактировал вопрос и поменял public int LoginGIA { get; set; } на public int? LoginGIA { get; set; }